# Symfony web test case JSON

Tags: json, symfony, functional-testing

How can I run a webtestcase agains an API? The default guide regarding functional tests only give the following command:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/some-url');
```

The Crawler class is a DOM crawler. I checked the reference for the FrameworkBundle\Client class and I couldn't find a method that will allow me to make a request that returns raw Response. At least that way, I will be able to json_decode the output and do my tests.

What can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After you do `$client->request(...)` call, you can do `$client->getResponse()` to get server response.

You can then assert status code and check it's contents, for example:

```
$client->request('GET', '/my-url');
$response = $client->getResponse();
$this->assertSame(200, $response->getStatusCode());
$responseData = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
// etc...
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a `PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertJson()` method since [this commit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/aa917f13818245b0492ca5e0bb026081a2104dca)
You can also test for a `Content-Type` response header.

```
$response = $client->getResponse();
$this->assertTrue($response->headers->contains('Content-Type', 'application/json'));
$this->assertJson($response->getContent());
$responseData = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
```

Answer (score 4):

The [willdurand/rest-extra-bundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaRestExtraBundle) bundle provides [additional helpers to test JSON](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaRestExtraBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#testing). To test equality there is already a built-in assertion for this purpose:

```
use Bazinga\Bundle\RestExtraBundle\Test\WebTestCase as BazingaWebTestCase;

// ...

$client->request('GET', '/my-url');
$response = $client->getResponse();
$this->assertJsonResponse($response, Response::HTTP_OK);
$this->assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString($expectedJson, $response);
```

Note that the `assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString` assertion will take in charge the normalization of both `$expectedJson` and `$response` strings.